# (Single Layer) Perceptron in PyTorch, bad convergence

Tags: pytorch, perceptron

I'm trying to develop a simple single layer perceptron with PyTorch (v0.4.0) to classify AND boolean operation.
I want to develop it by using autograd to calculate gradient of weights and bias and then update them in a SGD manner.

The code is very simple and is the following:

```
# AND points and labels
data = torch.tensor([
    [0, 0],
    [0, 1],
    [1, 0],
    [1, 1]
    ], dtype=torch.float32)
labels = torch.tensor([0,0,0,1], dtype=torch.float32)

weights = torch.zeros(2, dtype=torch.float32, requires_grad=True)
bias = torch.zeros(1, requires_grad=True)
losses = []
epochs = 100
eta = 0.01
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    for idx in range(4):
        # take current input
        X = data[idx,:]
        y = labels[idx]

        # compute output and loss
        out = torch.add(torch.dot(weights, X), bias)
        loss = (out-y).pow(2)
        total_loss += loss.item()
        # backpropagation
        loss.backward()

        # compute accuracy and update parameters
        with torch.no_grad():
            weights -= eta * weights.grad
            bias -= eta * bias.grad
            # reset gradient to zero
            weights.grad.zero_()
            bias.grad.zero_()
    losses.append(total_loss)
```

The model converges, as you can see from the learning curve 
[image: Loss over epochs]
but the resulting plane is:
[image: in orange the plane, the top-right plane has label 1, the others 0]

with 50% of accuracy.

I tried with different inital parameters and also by using the SGD optimizer from PyTorch but nothing changed.
I know that MSE is a regression loss but I don't think the problem is there.

Any ideas?

**Update**
The plane is computed with these 2 lines of code

```
xr = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
yr = (-1 / weights[1].item()) * (weights[0].item() * xr  + bias.item())
plt.plot(xr,yr,'-')
```

Comment: 1. The resulting plane looks correct to me. 2. Try changing the loss to NLL.

Comment: The plane is not correct because in the AND it should separate the top right point from all the others as it is the only one with label 1.

Comment: How did you compute the plane?

Comment: See the updated question above

Comment: How did you come up with the formula for `yr`? or where did you get it?

Comment: From the implicit plane equation `w0 * xr + w1 * yr + b = 0` you can get my formula by isolating `yr` and getting the explicit form used to plot the plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you use to compute the plane

```
yr = (-1 / weights[1].item()) * (weights[0].item() * xr  + bias.item())
```

is derived in the case where `y_i = [+1, -1]` and there is a sign function: it's computed by looking for the plane that separates positive and negative examples. This assumption is not valid anymore if you change targets.

If you draw this:

```
x1 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
x2 = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x1, x2)
w1, w2 = weights.detach().numpy()[0, 0], weights.detach().numpy()[1, 0]
b = bias.detach().numpy()[0]
Z = w1*X + w2*Y + b
```

which is the correct plane in 3D, you get the correct separation[image: plane in 3D space separating examples of different classes]

You can get a correct separation with your formula if you offset by a factor that depends on the average of the labels, like:

```
yr = (-1 / weights[1].item()) * (weights[0].item() * xr  + bias.item() - 0.5)
```

but I can't come around at justifying it formally.

Comment: Yes, it works for me.

With (-1, 1) labels the average, that is the offset at which the classification is made, is 0, but with (0,1) labels the offset is 0.5 so you have to subtract this value in order to get the previous case. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem in 2 different ways:

**Method 1 - Change labels in -1 and 1**
By simply changing labels from (0, 1) to (-1, 1) the plane is computed correctly.

Hence, the new labels (same data) are:

```
labels = torch.tensor([-1,-1,-1,1], dtype=torch.float32)
```

**Method 2 - Add a sigmoid function after out**
With (0, 1) labels, add a sigmoid function just after computing out, in this way:

```
out = torch.add(torch.dot(weights, X), bias)
out = torch.sigmoid(out)
```

I think that **method 1** accounts for the sign function of the perceptron, as the plan must discriminate points based on the sign of the output.
The **method 2** adapts this reasoning for (0,1) labels by using a squashing function.
These are just tentative, partial explanations. Try to comment below with more accurate ones.